# What to do when the Videos app freezes

Tags: video, performance, ipad

I started playing a video added from iTunes and about 10 minutes in the video stopped and the Videos app closed. Whenever I go back to the Videos app, it is a blank dark screen that won't respond to any input.

I tried doing a "force close" where I double hit the home button and then hold on a icon until I can press the minus. That didn't work. I restarted the iPad. Still nothing. I changed e settings so it doesn't start from where I left off. Still a dark screen.

It's an iPad 2 with whatever is the almost latest version. I'm on the road so I can't plug into my computer and get the latest version of iOS.

Comment: Hello. If the answer below helped you solve your issue, I'd suggest you please mark it as the accepted answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have the ability to perform a full reset (well, you can, but you won't have any personal data on it anymore, including whatever videos you're watching), I have a couple of suggestions.

First is a strange bug that I know has affected some iPad users and so might be an issue for you; it's one of those "how can these two things possibly be related" bugs.

Launch the Settings app and choose **General**=>**Reset**=>**Reset Network Settings**. All this will really mean is you'll lose your saved WiFi networks. If that doesn't solve it then I'd try the next suggestion (below), and if it doesn't work then in this same area choose **Reset All Settings**; I suggest trying this one third just because it means all of your apps will lose their stored settings and revert to their defaults, which is a hassle to manually restore.

Second, is it possible that your iPad is **full or near-full**? I've heard of this problem when there's so little space left that the Videos app can't even clear out any caches and so is stuck.

If so then you might try deleting a few things that you can get to. For example, delete some files in the iPod app, or delete any particularly large apps that you can live without until you next synch. Large apps include complex games (pretty much anything that renders 3 dimensions like first-person shooter, racing games, etc.) and apps with a lot of documents like iBooks or Pages or what have you. You can also delete photos via the Photos app if you have a bunch of large ones that are stored elsewhere.

After clearing out some space, restart your iPad again.

If all three of those fail then you're pretty much stuck with resetting your iPad, but again, that wipes everything and returns the device to its factory settings, which is likely not ideal in your situations since a restore requires your computer.